# How can I write set name in the circle in upset.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, venn-diagram

How can I write set name in the circle in upset.js

I have 2 problem.

1. how to write set name in venndiagram circle?
2. how to select full areas when i click outside?

Currently when I run my code it looks like this.

[image]

but, I want see like this.

[image]

```
 const elems = useMemo(
    () => [
      { name: "inner", sets: ["S1", "S2"] },
      { name: "left", sets: ["S1"] },
      { name: "right", sets: ["S2"] },
    ],
    []
  );
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<ISetLike<unknown> | unknown[] | null>(null);

  const sets = useMemo(() => extractSets(elems), [elems]);
  const combinations = useMemo(() => generateCombinations(sets), [sets]);

  const select = useCallback(
    (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setSelection(
        Array.from(e.target.closest('div')?.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>('input:checked') ?? []).map(
          (d) => d.valueAsNumber
        )
      );
    },
    [setSelection]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <VennDiagram
        sets={sets}
        combinations={combinations}
        width={250}
        height={150}
        selection={selection}
        onClick={setSelection}
        exportButtons={false}
      />
    </div>
  );
```